# Table with 2 primary key o how?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, create-table

I have a problem with a board from a project:

[image: Character Table]

This is the character table, the problem is that you should not be able to create 2 equal characters (same idStreamer and idViewer) but as they are not primary key this can happen.
Do you know how this can be solved?

Comment: Use composite primary keys

Comment: This is not clear.  (Are you talking about 2 columns being equal in one row? Or unique subrows? Or--?) Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When this is clear, it is very likely going to be a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a `UNIQUE` constraint on this tuple of columns to prevent the same pair of values to occur on several records:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT myconstraint UNIQUE (idStreamer, idViewer);
```

Comment: Pay attention -  both fields **must** be defined as `NOT NULL` - because `UNIQUE` constraint will not be checked if at least one field is NULL.

Comment: @Akina - Wrong (for MySQL).  The PK needs non-null values; `UNIQUE` does not.  Test case: `CREATE TABLE un (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    x INT NULL,
    y INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    UNIQUE(x,y)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO un (x,y) VALUES
    (1,2),
    (3,5),
    (1,NULL),
    (NULL,2),
    (NULL,2),
    (NULL,NULL);
SELECT * FROM un ORDER BY id;`

Comment: It is as if NULLs in a UNIQUE are all different.  (I think the manual says so somewhere.)

Comment: @RickJames I do NOT see anything relative to "primary key" in my comment or in the answer which my comment belongs to.